# Can HERE mobile SDKs be used in Japan?

Tags: dictionary, sdk, here-api

We're planning to develop a APP based on HERE mobile SDKs for Japanese users, Can HERE mobile SDKs (android and ios) be used for LBS services like location and navigation in Japan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, most probably the limited Japan map coverage is maybe an issue. There is no detailed Japan map with the HERE platform right now, and this means also no turn by turn guidance for example.

Btw: You can always check the public HERE Maps applications available in Apple AppStore and Google PlayStore if it satisfies your needs, since they also use the HERE MobileSDKs under the hood.

Comment: Thanks Marco for your reply. Is there any plan for supporting Japan detail map?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have sent an email to Here maps team, I have got below reply:

"Japan and mainland China maps are not available currently in any form(Online and Offline).
As mentioned we are in discussions with Chinese government to get the necessary agreement in place which will allow us to release the map for the China, however there is no confirmed date when it will happen."